# ESP8266 and https connection to firebase

Tags: arduino, esp8266

i am trying to send a push notification to android device from esp8266. i have wemos d1 mini board. my code is follows

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

#ifndef STASSID
//#define STASSID "XXXXXX"
//#define STAPSK  "XXXXXX"
#endif

const char* ssid = STASSID;
const char* password = STAPSK;
const char* host = "fcm.googleapis.com";
const int httpsPort = 80;
// Use web browser to view and copy // SHA1 fingerprint of the certificate
const char fingerprint[] PROGMEM = "0fd9151c4d4a317b647e87713bd7226b8b4fcbda";
WiFiClient client;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
  delay(500);
  Serial.print(".");
}

Serial.println("WiFi connected");
Serial.println("IP address: ");
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

//Use WiFiClientSecure class to create TLS connection
WiFiClientSecure client;
Serial.print("connecting to ");
Serial.println(host);
Serial.printf("Using fingerprint '%s'\n", fingerprint);
client.setFingerprint(fingerprint);
if (!client.connect(host, httpsPort)) {
Serial.println("connection failed");
return;
}
sendDataToFirebase();
}

void loop() {
}

void sendDataToFirebase() {
String data = "{" ;
data = data + "\"to\": \"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\"," ;
data = data + "\"notification\": {";
data = data + "\"body\": \"Motion detected\",";
data = data + "\"title\" : \"Alarm\" ";
data = data + "} }";
client.println("POST /fcm/send HTTP/1.1");
client.println("Authorization: key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,");
client.println("Content-Type: application/json");
client.println("Host: fcm.googleapis.com");
client.print("Content-Length: ");
client.println(data.length());
client.print("\n");
client.print(data);
Serial.println("Data sent...Reading response..");
//while (client.available()) {
//char c = client.read();
//Serial.print(c);
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.println(line);
//}
Serial.println("Finished!");
client.flush();
client.stop();
}
```

now my problem is, the connection to fcm server is failing. my best guess is, its for the fingerprint. 
I copied the thumbprint from https://firebase.google.com/. but the connection is still failing. Could you please help?

Comment: You can compile your sketch with "core debug level" to "verbose". This will give you a lot of info about the connection.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS uses port 443, not port 80. Change

```
const int httpsPort = 80;
```

to

```
const int httpsPort = 443;
```

Comment: This is not enough. If you use a 443 port, you need also a SSL certificate. So you have to download the server certificate to your esp before you can connect.

Comment: @john Hi John, thanks for the feedback. I did try that but no luck.

Comment: @Adriano i c. didint know that. Not sure actually how to do that. will give it a try.

Comment: @shahriar if you find a solution, I would like to know it. Since I am fighting with the same problem :D Now, I connect the ESP to my webserver and I send the notification over my webserver to the FCM. Since every app on Android sends a token and it is easier to save it on a server, than on the ESP. If you need the certificate, you just can copy the one from the browser (when you open the fcm page). But the problem is the expire date... So you should update your esp every 2-3 years...

Comment: @Adriano - that's what the fingerprint is for, which also changes with the certificate. Unfortunately, HTTPS support on the ESP has been a moving target.

Comment: @shahriar - are you getting the same error with port 443 - "connection failed"?

Comment: If you're using a recent version of the ESP8266 Arduino core (make sure it's up to date to do this), you can try doing 'client.setInsecure()'. You should never do this in production commercial code. It will keep your data transfer private, but you won't be able to verify the identity of the server you connect to.

Comment: Also - you mentioned you copied the fingerprint from firebase.google.com - it would use a different certificate than fcm.googleapis.com as they have different domain names. It's important to use the fingerprint for the endpoint you're trying to contact. I see a SHA1 fingerprint of `294E606B85EB4A884B40CEE23FBC0E256AC50645 ` for fcm.googleapis.com.

Answer (score 0):

The code sets the HTTPS fingerprint but accesses the server over HTTP (by using port 80). This is done via these parts of the code:

```
const char* host = "fcm.googleapis.com";
const int httpsPort = 80;

client.setFingerprint(fingerprint);
if (!client.connect(host, httpsPort)) {
```

The HTTPClient will have the error `Incoming protocol or record version is unsupported` with this configuration.

I set the port to 443 with your example code but found that the fingerprint is incorrect.

A successful connection occurs with the current fingerprint and with the following changes:

```
const int httpsPort = 443;
const char fingerprint[] PROGMEM = "bcc0d252e30c3f5040cb78126b50578fd60796c3";
```